# Javascript Regex to find any number (greater than 0) between two colons

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've tried this: `/:(/d+)/:/i`

and this: `/:/[1-9]*/:/i`

But nothing seems to work.
So ideally anything from `:1:` to `:9999999999999999999:` would be found

Comment: How do you plan to handle `:0001:` where it contains leading zeros but it is not a `0` value?

Comment: Try `/:(\d)+:/ig`. Tested on http://regexr.com/ and seems to be ok.

Comment: Is the string always `:nnnnnnn:` or does this pattern appear within another string? Are there multiples of this pattern within a string?

Comment: Those `/` inside the regex literal are invalid. Just remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/:(?!0*:)\d+:/
```

`(?!0*:)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if only `0`s are found between colons.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nA3sS9/2)